# Most efficient way to read and process UDP datagrams in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a very simple application that receives key/value objects via UDP. Each UDP packet contains a 16-byte key and the rest is the value. A `tokio::net::UdpSocket` is bound and used in the following loop:

```
let mut udp_socket = UdpSocket::bind(addr).await?;

loop {
    let mut data = Vec::with_capacity(MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE);
    let (len, _remote_addr) = udp_socket.recv_from(&mut data).await?;

    if len >= 16 {
        let key = (&data[..16]).to_vec();
        let value = (&data[16..len]).to_vec();;
        self.core.put_object(key, value);
    }
}
```

This works, but is rather inefficient, because both the key and value are copied by the `to_vec()` function. The following approach is already a little bit more efficient, because it won't copy the key:

```
let value = (&data[16..len]).to_vec();
let mut key = data;
key.truncate(16);
```

This approach has some disadvantages:

1. The `key` vector still retains MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE bytes (don't think using `shrink_to_fit` will help much).
2. The majority of the data (value bytes) is still copied.

Another option could be to use the same structure, but with the `value`. This would only result in copying 16 bytes and there would be less space lost, because the value is often larger than the key. I don't think this is possible, because the vector consists of a pointer, capacity and length. So you can't slice a vector in-place, because it's missing an offset.

The proper solution would be to use [vectored I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectored_I/O), but `UdpSocket::recv_from` doesn't support this.

When the key is removed, then the value is removed as well so both objects have the same lifetime. I was thinking of creating a new structure that owns the vector and can return slices to the key and value and work with that. But this would mean an overhaul of underlying code which makes it harder to read. So I am not sure if that's a decent solution. I also have two other interface (TCP and gRPC) that use the same underlying `put_object` method.

Any suggestions on how to deal with such an issue?

Comment: [`recv_from`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.1.0/tokio/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.recv_from) takes a mutable slice to write the incoming data, but you're always giving it an empty slice. Perhaps you wanted `vec![0; MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE]` instead?

Comment: My only suggestion would be to reuse `data` for each read instead of always re-allocating. If `put_object` is just storing what is sent, copying is a fine way to do it. But if its doing any parsing, I'd keep as much of that on the slice of `data` as possible before resorting to copying.

Comment: @kmdreko You’re right. Inhale vec! In my code. This was from an experiment tombes an uninitialized vector. The code that uses 2x tovec reused the buffer, but I want to get rid of the copy operation. When I pass and store the buffer itself, then I need to allocate it over and over again.

Comment: Tokio *does* support vectored I/O, and has so for a while. See [`try_recv_buf_from`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.1.0/tokio/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.try_recv_buf_from) and [`chain_mut`](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.0.1/bytes/buf/trait.BufMut.html#method.chain_mut). Have you tried that?

Comment: @LambdaFairy I just tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. I chain two buffers together (16 bytes + 64KB) and pass that buffer to [`try_recv_buf_from`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.1.0/tokio/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.try_recv_buf_from). On Windows it fails, because the datagram doesn't fit the buffer and on Linux it returns only the first 16 bytes and discards the rest. I checked the [source](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/cc0911aa645cbaf5dee5b3d51efcfbe703159902/tokio/src/net/udp.rs#L816) and it seems to simply call `recv_from`, so it's not real vectored I/O.

Comment: If that doesn't work, it's a bug in Tokio. I recommend reporting it.